# Is `git push --force` ever harmful when applied to your origin contributor fork in Github workflow?

Tags: git, github

Assume we contributors who are using the Github workflow. That is, there are three repos:

- The project owner's, which we locally call "upstream". We don't have write-access to this.
- Our public (github) "fork", which we locally call "origin". We push our commits to this repo and open pull requests with the owner to have them merge these commits into their repo.
- Our "local", private, repo. The repo on which we do immediate work and from which we push commits (to our origin repo).

Let's say we locally create a topic-branch, do a series of commits, push those commits to our origin, and open a pull request on Github. The pull request will list those commits and we wait for the owner to respond.

Imagine we identify a mistake in all (or some) of the just pushed commit messages.

Would editing those commit messages (using an interactive rebase e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~3`) and then force pushing those changes (`git push --force`) ever be harmful in either case:

- The owner has not yet merged the pull request (into their repo);
- The owner has merged the pull request (into their repo);

?

I ask in the light of general warnings against `git push --force`. For example at https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/ there's ...

> We strongly discourage force pushing, since this changes the history of your repository. If you force push, people who have already cloned your repository will have to manually fix their local history.

But in a github/integration-manager workflow context (as opposed to a Centralized workflow) that warning wouldn't seem to apply given that others are not usually forking your project.

So some ancillary questions seem pertinent:

- If we are merely force pushing commits that change the commit messages, rather than changing the actual work done, does that (also) guarantee safety?
- Does a project owner ever pull changes from your (origin) repo, before making decisions on your pull request? Does this matter?
- Would using `--force-with-lease` (See https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/) further guarantee safety?

Comment: Your earlier pull request may have already been pulled, in which case, the pull-er (who got your earlier commits) now has them saved by *ID* rather than merely as a name ("pull request #nnn"). By force-pushing you replace the name-to-ID mapping—your fixed commit messages all have new IDs—but it *may* be too late. Only the pull-er knows, though.

Comment: (In other words, the answer to the middle bullet point—"does a project owner ever pull changes ... before making decisions"—is definitely yes. In fact, they can't really decide *until* they have copied the commits, although they can look first—a sort of eyeball/web-browser-only copy—then make a decision, then push a button that copies again and then merges. It's up to them.)

Comment: Thanks torek, that crystallizes a few things, including: 1. That a project owner could well pull down your commits before they make a decision on the pull request (e.g. by pulling into their local repo, into an experimental branch). and 2. They may have merged or closed your pull request before you know it. 3. Changing commits (through rebasing) will change the name-to-ID mapping. My question, therefore, is: does that name-to-ID mapping overwrite necessarily cause problems for the owner if they've pulled your original commits AND you are only changing the messages?

Comment: I would not say "cause problems for them" so much as maybe give *you* heartburn later, when you find they have incorporated your original commits instead of your revised ones.  If you use `git rebase` to switch back to your original chain of commits, and the message is the only thing that changed, rebase will automate the soothing of this heartburn: it will detect that the upstream commit has the same patch-ID, and believe *they* "improved" *your* commit message, as it were.

Comment: In the end, it's really a matter of how fast you are, and how cooperative or combative you and they may be in case of the need to revise commits. If you watch, e.g., Linux mailing lists, the process is very cooperative: someone posts a series of commits as email patches—it might also be available via pulling, but it's reviewed through email—and people comment and the patches get revised and go out as v2, v3, and so on until everyone is happy (or has given up :-) ). Then the maintainer, whoever that is, takes the final version.

Comment: At this point I posted my own answer to my question. Thanks again for your comments, torek.

Answer (score 1):

### Sharpening the Question

In the light of @torek's helpful comments I'll try and sharpen the question, "Is `git push --force` ever harmful when applied to your origin contributor fork in Github workflow?", before attempting to answer it myself.

Consider two scenarios where you might be tempted to rebase. When you want to:

- Change your files that contradict prior commits.
- Change only prior commit messages.

Neither kind of rebasing is a problem if you have not yet pushed commits to a public repo.

Consider, however, when you have already pushed commits to a public repo and you want to revise them:

- When you want to change your files that contradict prior commits there's no problem in just incorporating those changes into a new commit (or commits), or performing a git `revert` which rewinds changes through creating new commit(s). That is, rebasing is unnecessary in this scenario. (I take it when torek is exemplifying a collaborative approach to pull requests, as on the Linux mailing list, torek wants to pick out this case).
- When you want to change only prior commit messages. The motive for this could be that the prior commit message(s) could wrongly identify the files changed, or otherwise wrongly describe the commit(s). You'd rather have the right message in the history in order not to confuse future readers.

So the only scenario to further consider is when you want only to change prior commit messages. Then there are further specific scenarios to consider under the Github workflow. Those with respect to the pull request against which you are tempted to push rebased commits:

1. The pull request is open.

   a. And the project owner has pulled down commits from the pull request in order to evaluate the pull request. (Thanks again @torek for alerting me to this case).
2. The pull request has been merged by the project owner.
3. The pull request has been closed (without a merge by the project owner).

Do any of these scenarios cause harm?

### Experiments to Test the Question

I've preformed some experiments with Github accounts as an owner and contributor against scenario 1a. I've seen that it gets messy very quickly at the owner's end and the contributor's end. The mess entails that:

- Although I can make both sides return to a equivalent state eventually, it becomes tricky to get there. The right combination of pushes, pulls and merges are somewhat labyrinth.
- And because I've deliberately chosen to see what the messy state looks like, and not to clean things up as suggested by torek ...

  > if you use `git rebase` to switch back to your original chain of commits, and the message is the only thing that changed, rebase will automate the soothing of this heartburn

  ... I've seen that the messy state in effect duplicates the commits that were rebased; and it's not clear, just by a quick look at the commit log ...

  [Owner: John Creator; contributor: John Luke Bentley]

  [image: Pull request opened and the project owner has pulled down commits from the pull request in order to evaluate the pull request; Commits after interactive rebase, to change message only, have been pushed back up to the pull request; the owner has merged changes; then both parties pull to make their repos into an equivalent state]

  ... which set of commits are the relevant ones. That confusion exists in both the owner's local repo and the contributor's local repo (because they are now in an equivalent state).

That's enough to not even bother considering scenarios 2 and 3.

### The Concluding Answer

Given that confusion and mess I think it is probably best to adhere to the general advice ...

> Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository. (Chacon and Straub 2014, ch. 3 Git Branching, sec. Rebasing, 119) ...
>
> [You could] rebase local changes you’ve made but haven’t shared yet before you push them in order to clean up your story [if necessary], but never rebase anything you’ve pushed somewhere. (Chacon and Straub 2014, ch. 3 Git Branching, sec. Rebasing, 124).

In short, avoid `git push --force` (or `git push --force-with-lease`) ... unless you have some exceptional reason for doing so and know what you are doing.

For noobs like me who don't know what they are doing that translates into two (relatively) simple rules:

1. **Do not rebase commits that exist outside your local repository and don't use `git push --force` (nor `git push --force-with-lease`);** and
2. **Carefully review commits before pushing them.**

It might be better to view commits already pushed outside your repo just like emails that have been sent: they are out in the world for good or ill. The best strategy for correcting commits, for content or just the message, is to send an additional addendum, either as:

- An additional commit (with its own ID and timestamp, not a rebased commit);
- A comment on the pull request; or
- A comment via some other medium to the owner (email, SMS, etc).

I'd be very much open to others posting alternative answers or providing further comment.

### References

- Chacon, Scott, and Ben Straub. 2014. Pro Git. 2nd ed. New York, NY: Apress. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2.